# FormData is not defined - Firefox 3.6.28 alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I have the great job of having to finish off a job originally given to a contractor but was never completed. Not a problem however I've now been told that the system must support Firefox 3.6! Not great but not something I would lose sleep over until now! The system has a Ajax function that uses the FormData object and then uploads a document (usually a PDF). I've ran this through Firefox 3.6 and I get the following

> "FormData is not defined"
>   var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

That's fine as I can see that this object isn't supported, I just need to use a different method or means of collection... I used this:

```
var formData = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/files/formdata;1"]
        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMFormData);
```

However this gave me the following error!

> Permission denied for http://10.29.100.23:8080 to get property
>   XPCComponents.classes

I was unsure why this was... is the path "`@mozilla.org/files/formdata;1`" incorrect? I did more research and was getting nowhere! So I then thought about serializing the form  changed the following to...

```
var formData =  {};

$.each($('form')[0].serializeArray(), function(_, kv) {
     if (formData.hasOwnProperty(kv.name)) {
         formData[kv.name] = $.makeArray(formData[kv.name]);
         formData[kv.name].push(kv.value);
     }else {
        formData[kv.name] = kv.value;
    }
});
```

although this didn#t error the Ajax function wasn't uploading (I presume it wasn't recognizing or finding the file or it was just collecting a string for the file value). Does anyone have any recommendations on an alternative for FormData in older browsers, especially Firefox 3.6 - that's the only old browser I have to support.

** *update* ****

this is the content of the form on the HTML page

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" target="#">
    <label for="fileField">Rechnung hochladen</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField">
    <progress id="progressbar" class="progressbar_margin hidden"></progress>
</form>
```

Comment: What elements are contained within the form? If they're non-file inputs, you should be able to just use `$('theForm').serialize()` as the `data` property of the `.ajax()` call.

Comment: the form is simple and consists of the following (see the original question)

Comment: If the question can be rephrased as "use ajax for file uploads" then this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686099/file-upload-via-ajax-within-jquery  The http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ page says it supports firefox 3.6+. There is an apparently more up to date fork at https://github.com/bencolon/file-uploader

Answer (score 3):

[FormData](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/formdata-interface-coming-to-firefox/) is an XMLHttpRequest Level 2 interface that makes it easy to submit a form (including file uploads) using XHR / Ajax. As you've discovered, it's only available in Firefox from version 4 onwards. (The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) has a browser compatibility table.)

I suggest trying the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). It supports an iframe fallback for uploading files in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this before your code:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege(
    'UniversalXPConnect'
);
```

To be sure also do this:

1. type "about:config" in your address bar;
2. search for "signed.applets.codebase_principal_support" ;
3. Set the value to true;

Hope it works , good luck.