# copy html input file element from one form to another

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a requirement like follows i have a file element in one form this form contains many 
other fields also so i cannot submit it but after the file has chosen i need to upload that 
so i created the second form with iframe. I am not able to copy the file element from one form to another especially in ie i tried with cloneNode and appendChild both are not working any suggestions. i am really stuck.

```
<form name ="form1">
   <input type="file"/>
</form>

<form name="form2">       
<form>
```

Comment: Why not use fileuploadui js plugin? It does the background upload process for you.

Comment: i have created my own file upload component so cannot use any other plugins. any simple solutions.

Comment: You should check event for propertychange and when it changes submit the first form into iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [cloneNode](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/m3942/) has allowed to clone file inputs. Possible code may be as follows:

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input id="file1" type="file" onchange="copy_file_input()" />
</form>
<form name="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="form2sent" />
</form>
```

```js
function copy_file_input() {
  var target_form = document.forms.form2;
  if (target_form.file2 != undefined) {
    target_form.removeChild(target_form.file2);
  }
  var elem = document.getElementById('file1');
  var copy = elem.cloneNode(true);
  copy.name = 'file2';
  target_form.appendChild(copy);
}
```

Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1686201/1422309) may be useful.

Comment: Hi i did the same its working but server side i am not receiving any data.

Comment: @saravananshanmugavel You are right, I tested it and it couldn't make a copy of selected file. Can you try if this update will work?