# Upload a file using PHP with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using AJAX and PHP.

I already do it using forms:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="file" id="idFile" name="fileName" />
</form>
```

And it works very well, but I really need to do it with AJAX.

I already have my php script which uploads the file. I want this script to be excecuted whith AJAX. I want my javascript function to do something like this:

```
function uploadFile(file) {
    var url = "upload.php?file="+file; //<-- Can I do this?

    xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (!xmlhttp) {
       alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
       return;
   }
   var xml = xmlhttp;
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xml.readyState == 4) {
         alert("THE FILE WAS UPLOADED");
      }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
   xmlhttp.send(null);

   return true;
}
```

My question is:
Is it posible to pass a file-type variable this way? If not, which is the way I can pass the file variable? Can I use `document.getElementById("idFile").value` ?

I hope someone could help me
Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686099/file-upload-via-ajax-within-jquery

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks I know, I didn't writte it complete because I already have that way working very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in this way.

```
<form method="POST" id="formLic" name="formLic" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="lnumero">Número: </label>
   <input type="text" id="lnumero"/>
   <label for="larchivo">Archivo: </label>
   <input type="file" id="larchivo"/>
</form>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("form#formLic").submit(function(){
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "nuevo/uploadInsert.php", // file where you save your data and files
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    // action or message 
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't upload files via AJAX. You should use hidden iframe instead.

File upload by ajax is introduced in XHR2 [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object but this is not supported by old browsers. See browsers [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/xhr2).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't upload files with Ajax. Have a look at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/